# How to cite multiple authors in full for the first time, and using et al. for following citations with biblatex for APA 6

Tags: biblatex, apa6, multiple-citations

I would like to define options in the biblatex preamble so that only first citations with multiple authors are spelled out, all following abbreviated to author et al., as APA6 requires. My preamble looks like this, what is missing to generate “author et al.” ?

```
\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    backend=biber,
    maxcitenames=7,
    doi=true,
    isbn=false,
    uniquename=false,
    url=true,
]{biblatex}
```

A similar question was asked here:
[How to cite a document with multiple authors using natbib [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219259/how-to-cite-a-document-with-multiple-authors-using-natbib)

I tried a few options as suggested at the above link, and I reviewed the BibLaTex documentation, what function am I looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `style=apa6` should solve your problem (you will need the `biblatex-apa6` package). The `apa` style currently takes the 7th version of APA style into account, which has changed in-line citations of works with multiple authors.

Comment: Thanks!!! I was just reading over the biblatex-apa documentation, and recalled APA7 is out, didn't think that would make a difference for my little problem. style=apa6 does the trick!!!